# Running jruby application with Elastic Search gem.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, elasticsearch, jruby, warbler

I'm trying to generate a compiled application of the Rails project using `jruby` and host it on `Tomcat server`.
I'm struggling to establish the connection with `elasticsearch` after  compiling.

Following are the steps I've taken:

- Installed `Jruby-9.2.0.0`
- Created a `jruby on rails` application
- Gemfile contains

  `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
   gem 'listen'
   gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
   gem 'therubyrhino'
   gem 'java'
   gem 'ruby-debug', '~> 0.10.6'
   gem 'elasticsearch' 
   gem 'warbler'`
- `warble.conf` contains

  `Warbler::Config.new do |config|
    config.features = %w(FEATURE)
    config.features = %w(gemjar)
  end`
- Controller contains:

  `def index
    $es_client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
    products = $es_client.search index: 'production-products'
    render json: products
  end`
- Ran `warble compiled war` command in the project folder to create `.war` file

When I run the application directly using `rails s` it is working as expected.

But when I compile the application and run on Tomcat server I'm getting the following error

```
Internal Server Error (500)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/blog/
java.lang.NullPointerException
You're seeing this error because you use    JRuby::Rack::ErrorApp::ShowStatus.
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to include the required gem in `warble.conf` file.

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.features = %w(FEATURE)
  config.features = %w(gemjar)
  config.gems["elasticsearch"]
end+
```